# Why do I get this error?

Tags: perl, json

This is my code

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -T

use CGI;
use CGI::Carp qw(fatalsToBrowser);
use CGI qw(:standard);
use JSON;
use utf8;
use strict;
use warnings;


# ... ;

my $cgi = CGI->new;
$cgi->charset('UTF-8');

my @owners = map { s/\s*//g; $_ } split ",", $cgi->param('owner');
my @users  = map { s/\s*//g; $_ } split ",", $cgi->param('users');


my $json = JSON->new;
$json = $json->utf8;


my %user_result = ();
foreach my $u (@users) {
    $user_result{$u} = $db1->{$u}{displayName};
}

my %owner_result = ();
foreach my $o (@owners) {
    $owner_result{$o} = $db2{$o};
}

$json->{"users"}   = $json->encode(\%user_result);
$json->{"owners"}  = $json->encode(\%owner_result);

$json_string = to_json($json);

print $cgi->header(-type => "application/json", -charset => "utf-8");
print $json_string;
```

and these lines

```
$json->{"users"}   = $json->encode(\%user_result);
$json->{"owners"}  = $json->encode(\%owner_result);
```

gives the error

```
Not a HASH reference
```

Why do I get that?

How can that be fixed?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A `JSON` object (at least in the XS version, see below) is just a SCALAR reference, so you can't perform a hash reference operation on it. In practice, most of the Perl objects you encounter will be hash references, but this will not always be the case.

I'm not sure what you are trying to accomplish by using JSON to encode a JSON object. Do you need to encode the internals of the JSON object? Or do you just need to serialize the user and owner data? In the latter case, you should just use a new hash reference to hold that data and pass to JSON. If you really do require an encoding of the JSON object, you might have some better luck using `JSON::PP` (the "Pure Perl" variant of the JSON module), which does use a hash reference.

Comment: "you should just use a new hash reference to hold that data and pass to JSON". That is exactly what I am trying to do. =) How do I do that?

Comment: `my $data; \n $data->{users} = $json->encode(\%user_result); \n $data->{owners} = $json->encode(\%owner_result); \n $json_string = to_json($data);`, for one way

Answer (score 2):

Looks to me that `$json = $json->utf8;` is replacing the $json hash ref with a scalar, the result of $json->utf8.

Before the lines that assign to $json->{...}, use Dumper from the Data::Dumper module to see what is in it.

```
use Data::Dumper;
print Dumper($json);
```

Comment: Then I get `$VAR1 = undef;` also if I remove the utf-8 line.

Comment: @Sandra Schlichting: I think you are doing it in the wrong place; put the `print Dumper($json);` just before `$json->{"users"}   = $json->encode(\%user_result);`

Answer (score 2):

Because $json in your case is encoder itself, which is reference to SCALAR. Try to have different variable to hold your result. Something like

```
my %json_result = (users => $json->encode(\%user_result),
                   owners => $json->encode(\%owner_result));
```

Answer (score 2):

Your big problem is that `$json` is the JSON encoder object, not the data structure to be encoded.  You should be making a separate data structure.

Your other problem is that you're trying to double encode your JSON.  This code:

```
my $data; # I've added this to fix your first bug
$data->{"users"}   = $json->encode(\%user_result);
$data->{"owners"}  = $json->encode(\%owner_result);

$json_string = to_json($data);
```

would create a JSON string that, when decoded, would give you a hash with two keys.  The value of each key would be a string containing a JSON-encoded hash.  It makes more sense for each value to be a hash.

So, try this:

```
my $json_string = $json->encode({
  users  => \%user_result,
  owners => \%owner_result,
});
```

Here, I'm using an anonymous hashref, because there's no need to give the hash to be encoded a name.  We're only using it once.